# Container Row height auto fill/adjust with CSS

Tags: css, row-height

I have a container(wrapper) with two rows of containers and i gave both rows' height value as auto so that it can be dynamically resize based on the content within it (instead of giving specific height for each row e.g. row-top height 46% and row-bottom 54%). I'm trying to get the bottom row container's height to auto fill out the screen with CSS (*Not with JavaScript). Please check the image attached below for the intended result. Please advice, thank you.

[Click here for preview at JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uC8/)

HTML

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="row-top">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div> 
    <div id="row-bottom">
        <iframe id="gmap"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content-wrapper {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width:600px;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#row-top {
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:blue;
}

#row-bottom {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

iframe#gmap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%   
}
```

[Click here for preview at JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uC8/)

**Intended Result:**

[image: Should looks like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>There's no way using common CSS.</del>

If you want to use common CSS you have to set `display` to `table` on the container, and on the children use the value `table-row`. Now, the specs don't define how to calculate the height of the (anonymous) cells, but if you set `height` to `100%` it seems to work (at least on Firefox).

You can also do it using CSS property defined in [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/), which isn't [properly supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in some old versions of some browsers.

However, with this new layout module you would only have to set `display` to `flex` and `flex-direction` to `column` on the container. This way you get a layout like the normal block layout, but setting `flex` to `1` for the second row, this will be forced to take all the space left.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uC8/1/ (tested on Chrome and Firefox only)

Comment: Thx for your recommendation, really appreciate. However that's still not what i'm trying to achieve because that'll require to set a specific height for the container of the two rows in order to get that work plus it (the green row) does not fill out the remaining gap at the bottom of the screen. P.S. Tested on firefox 25 and chrome 31

Comment: You can also set `height` to `100%`, as in your code. Isn't that what you are aiming for? Here the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4uC8/2/

Comment: Yes, you're right. i just realise that the reason that it doesn't work as you mentioned earlier was because the the html, body wasn't set to height:100% at jsfiddle. Thank you so much. Unfortunately this will not work on IE below 10 cause i thought i could find a trick to get this achieve like the columns.

Comment: i see what i've missed earlier :) thank you so much Carlo! That's exactly what i was hoping to achieve!